# Python adding grouplayer to muliple maps

Tags: arcpy

I have the following code which is supposed to add a one group layer to each of the maps. In this case the group layer is always the same.

Desired output:

```
Map1 = 1 group layer added
Map2 = 1 group layer added
Map3 = 1 group layer added
```

However this is the result I am getting:

```
Map1 = 1 group layer added
Map2 = 2 group layers added
Map3 = 3 group layers added
```

Can someone tell me why/how the results are being compounded?

Note: I used to have this code within a "for" loop. Split it out so could try to figure out why not working correctly.

```
    SDESurveyed = (r"M:\projects\SDE Surveyed Layers")

    #This grouplayer is blank. Used because Python currently cannot create a grouplayer on it's own
    ClientLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\TOOLS\PythonTools\ClientSurveyedData.lyr")

    #Look for group layer the matches Client name
    for filename in os.listdir(SDESurveyed):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename[:-4], Client):
            surveyedFile = SDESurveyed + "\\" + filename
            #Create a layer file to the path
            SDElayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(surveyedFile)


    #SDEkeys = ["AC_","CN_","AM_"]
   # for item in mxd:
        #if item in SDEkeys:
            #imxd = mxd[item]
    imxd = mxd["CN_"]
    print imxd
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(imxd,"Project Area")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "*", df):
        if lyr.name == "ClientSurveyedData":
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
            print("PREVIOUS CLIENT DATA LAYER REMOVED...")
    print("ADDING NEW CLIENT DATA LAYER...")

    targetClientLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "COMPANY SURVEYED DATA", df)[0]

    # Add the layer to the layer group
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetClientLayer, ClientLayer, "BOTTOM")

    #Target Layer to where layer will open 
    targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "ClientSurveyedData", df)[0]

    # Add the layer to the layer group
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, SDElayer, "BOTTOM")
    print "LOOPED"
    imxd.save()
    #del targetClientLayer
    #del targetGroupLayer

    imxd = mxd["AM_"]
    print imxd
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(imxd,"Project Area")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "*", df):
        if lyr.name == "ClientSurveyedData":
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
            print("PREVIOUS CLIENT DATA LAYER REMOVED...")
    print("ADDING NEW CLIENT DATA LAYER...")

    targetClientLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "COMPANY SURVEYED DATA", df)[0]

    # Add the layer to the layer group
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetClientLayer, ClientLayer, "BOTTOM")

    #Target Layer to where layer will open 
    targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "ClientSurveyedData", df)[0]

    # Add the layer to the layer group
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, SDElayer, "BOTTOM")
    print "LOOPED"
    imxd.save()

    imxd = mxd["AC_"]
    print imxd
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(imxd,"Project Area")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "*", df):
        if lyr.name == "ClientSurveyedData":
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
            print("PREVIOUS CLIENT DATA LAYER REMOVED...")
    print("ADDING NEW CLIENT DATA LAYER...")

    targetClientLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "COMPANY SURVEYED DATA", df)[0]

    # Add the layer to the layer group
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetClientLayer, ClientLayer, "BOTTOM")

    #Target Layer to where layer will open 
    targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "ClientSurveyedData", df)[0]

    # Add the layer to the layer group
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, SDElayer, "BOTTOM")
    print "LOOPED"
    imxd.save()
```

Comment: Are your RemoveLayers really needed?  It seems like you are just trying to empty your group layer which could be brought in afresh from your empty layer file.  I suspect that in trying to do this your mxd.saves are keeping it in each successive map.

Comment: The RemoveLayers is there because say the program is run once and the layer is added to the map. If the program is run again I don't want it to add another layer if it exists. I have tried doing a arcpy.mapping.exists if statement, but found the removeLayer and add fresh worked better in my situation.

Comment: You could perhaps delete the MapDocument object and then create it afresh rather than trying to empty it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ending up getting it to work by doing this...

However I feel like this about my code [http://imgur.com/gallery/x0ml8](https://imgur.com/gallery/x0ml8)

```
SDEkeys = ["AC_","CN_","AM_"]

    addSDE = True
    for item in mxd:
        if item in SDEkeys:
            imxd = mxd[item]
            print imxd
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(imxd,"Project Area")[0]
            for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "*", df):
                if lyr.name == "ClientSurveyedData":
                    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
                    print("PREVIOUS CLIENT DATA LAYER REMOVED...")
            print("ADDING NEW CLIENT DATA LAYER...")

            targetClientLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "COMPANY SURVEYED DATA", df)[0]

            # Add the layer to the layer group
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetClientLayer, ClientLayer, "BOTTOM")

            #Target Layer to where layer will open 
            targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "ClientSurveyedData", df)[0]

            # Add the layer to the layer group

            if addSDE == True:
                arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, SDElayer, "BOTTOM")
                addSDE = False
            else:
                pass
            print "LOOPED"
            imxd.save()
```